# How can I import an entire project in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, import

I'm trying to import an entire project in Android Studio to my actual one.
However, when I choose File->Import Project, it just opens new window with this
project I need import,
without anything importing in. What's wrong ?

Also I do not know how to reference to the imported project.

**EDIT**

**I have now imported my old module, but I do not know how to use it:** (I have added my module via `project structure`) but its functions are still invisible.

[image]

```
$ grep -ri click4 .
grep: ./app8/build/intermediates/dex/debug/mergeProjectDexDebug/classes.dex: binary file matches
grep: ./app8/build/intermediates/javac/debug/classes/com/exampleC/layouttable24/MainActivity$1.class: binary file matches
grep: ./app8/build/intermediates/javac/debug/classes/com/exampleC/layouttable24/MainActivity.class: binary file matches
grep: ./app8/build/intermediates/project_dex_archive/debug/out/com/exampleC/layouttable24/MainActivity$1.dex: binary file matches
grep: ./app8/build/intermediates/project_dex_archive/debug/out/com/exampleC/layouttable24/MainActivity.dex: binary file matches
./app8/src/main/java/com/exampleC/layouttable24/M:                        click4(view);
./app8/src/main/java/com/exampleC/layouttable24/M:    public void click4(View view) {
./app8/src/main/java/com/exampleC/layouttable24/MainActivity.java:                        click4(view);
./app8/src/main/java/com/exampleC/layouttable24/MainActivity.java:    public void click4(View view) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **File->New->Import Module**

Comment: Please, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72319383/an-imported-module-cannot-be-used-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 1):

Just open the project in which you want to import the existing project and then go to

**File->New->Import Module**

And then just configure the project

Comment: Please, see my **EDIT**.