# An Imported Module cannot be used in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, import

I'm trying to use my **imported module** as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41764338/importing-module-in-android-studio),
but I got stuck as in the picture below. What to click now to use my `:app8` module  ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Before clicking the **+** button select the module first in which you want to add dependency and then try to add dependency it should work.